# Easy way to get the weekday in a batch file

Tags: date, batch-file, dayofweek, weekday

I was searching for a good easy answer to getting the day of the week from %date% and saw a lot of answers but none very eloquent.

Comment: I don't see a question here. If you're looking for improvements to your working code, please ask in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Otherwise, please move your solution to the Answers section of this page and rewrite your question to be an actual question.

Comment: This is not an on topic question. What you are expected to do is post a specific programming problem. Then if you wish to self answer, you submit that answer in the appropriate location. I have therefore removed all of your answer content from your question. As a result your question no longer makes sense as a request for programming code assistance. Please improve it, before submitting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for it, so here it is!

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do set /A "M=1%%a-100,D=1%%b-100,Y=%%c"
set /A "DOW=( D + 30*(M-1)+M/2+(M>>3)*(M&1) - !(((2-M)>>31)+1)*(2-!(Y%%4)) +6)%%7+1"
for /F "tokens=%DOW%" %%a in ("Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday") do echo %date% is %%a
```

This is a *"good easy answer to getting the day of the week from %date%"*. However, I'm afraid I don't understand what *"very eloquent"* means... **`;)`**

This formula assumes that `%date%` show the date in MM/DD/YYYY format. If the order is a different one, just change the `M` and `D` variables in the formula.

This method requires a small adjustment every new year: just change the `+6` adjustment to a value that get the right day of week on Jan/1st of the new year (the value must be between 0 and 6). This is done in order to keep the method "simple and easy"...

Comment: The first `for` command line must be `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in ("%date%") do set /A "D=1%%a-100,M=1%%b-100,Y=%%c"` for a German date like `18.07.2023` with a dot as separator instead of a slash and day before month in date string. A German user should use also German weekday names and the German verb `ist` instead of English verb `is`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using Powershell command :

```
@echo off
Title Get and Show The day of the week
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Powershell -C "(Get-Date).ToString('dddd')"') do Set "DayOfWeek=%%a"
echo( The day of the Week is %DayOfWeek%
Pause
```

Comment: That is also nice and works even on English Windows 7 with PowerShell 2.0. It outputs the weekday in the language configured for the user account which is German in my case while the OS language is English.